# How to query efficiently (by cost) in DynamoDB (Moving from RDS)

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am just new in NoSQL and DynamoDB. I try to moving from using AWS RDS to DynamoDB.

I have table user which can have more than one of work experiences and can have more than one of interest (table of interest have master data in interest table). There will be a lot query filtering by user by their work experiences and interest. Example: Find user who have work experiences title is 'Programmer' or find user who have interest is 'SQL, NoSQL'.

```
User Table:
- user_id (PK)
- name
- birthdate
- ...

Work Experience Table:
- user_id (PK)
- work_sequence_id (PK)
- work_title
- work_description

Interest Table:
- interest_id (PK)
- interest_name

User Interest Table:
- user_id (PK)
- interest_id (PK)
```

So I try to convert it to DynamoDB:

```
User Table:
- user_id (PK/Partition Key)
- name
- birth_date
- ...

Work Experience Table:
- user_id (PK)
- work_sequence_id (SK/Sort Key)
- work_title (global secondary index)
- work_description
```

For the interest table, I want to re-structure the table. Basically, beside filtering user by interest, I just want to get the most popular interest for suggestion word (filter by word that contain 'search_word'). Example if there is 7 user have interest in 'SQL' and 10 user have interest in 'NoSQL'. When user search the word 'SQ' the word 'NoSQL' will appear first and 'SQL' will appear second.

So I create like this:

```
User Interest Table:
- user_id (PK)
- interest_name (SK)

Interest Table:
- interest_name (PK)
- count (SK)
```

Then I will use the count to get the popular interest.

Usually I use the join to get user data, work experiences, and interests also using aggregated function to get most popular interest. Now I need to use four query operator to get all the data. Basically, I need efficiently and effectively store the data in term of cost.

Do you have any database design suggestion for this scenario in DynamoDB?

Comment: dynamodb is not meant for this use case, you have ported you relational schema to a nosql database,which is not a good idea. you can use dynamodb to store your data and elastic search to serve the above use cases, instead of querying like you are doing right now. What is the scale you are running on? and what is the problem that you are facing with RDS?

Comment: Still using free tier and there is no issue in RDS right now because I am still in development. However my friends said I better to change my DB to NoSQL like DynamoDB because I create Tinder like application which will have a lot of write transaction (such as swiping and chat). Is it better keep using RDS or switching to DynamoDB?

Comment: yes, chat can go in nosql (since there are very limited access patterns i.e. get message for one user sorted by time and few more). But here you are talking about diverse usecase which can evolve over time. Hence NoSql is not a good choice.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just answering your question why I am moving into NoSQL database. Can you explain more detail why NoSQL is not a good choice and please also give the solution.

Comment: with the above schema you will do an application level join (Get from table A, select few values, get from table b where some value=few value). This will be more costly than SQL DB doing the join for you, because in SQL you can optimise these access patterns. But in your case, there will be lots of data to and fro. Even if nosql get will be fast for fetching one row, you wont notice any performance gain since your scale is not high.